# Does the ActionMailer.deliveries mail queue get cleared on each test instance or do I have to empty it myself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, actionmailer

```
assert !ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?, "Queue is empty"
```

If I have two unit tests that send mail, and I want to check in each that the queue is not empty, will I have to reset the queue in the second test (to clear anything that might be in there from the first test)?

Rails 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to empty it yourself because `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` will persist between tests (It is a singleton). You should always clear the deliveries array before any test runs to ensure it is empty.